Switch language menu Codeigniter 4
I am a beginner in codeigniter, I am using version 4 to create a multilingual application, I have applied all the steps but it cannot work correctly. Manually it works, i.e., by typing the link address, like this: http://localhost/app/en or http://localhost/app/fr. However, it does not work when clicking on a language in the language menu, no effect occurs. How could you help me please?
I used a function in a helper that can display the list of languages ​​with the following contents:
Here is part of the content of the helper function:
function supported_languages()
{
    $supported_languages = json_decode('{
        "en":{
            "name":"English",
            "nativeName":"english"
        },
        "es":{
            "name":"Spanish",
            "nativeName":"español"
        },
        "fr":{
            "name":"French",
            "nativeName":"français"
        }
    }');
    $all_languages = json_decode('{
        "ab":{
            "name":"Abkhaz",
            "nativeName":"аҧсуа"
        },
        "za":{
            "name":"Zhuang, Chuang",
            "nativeName":"Saɯ cueŋƅ, Saw cuengh"
        }
    }');

    return $supported_languages;

    //    die(var_dump($list));
}

**
This is a langage menu**:
<!-- Menu langue -->
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <!-- <i class="far fa-bell"></i>  -->
            <i class="fa fa-language"></i> 
            <span><?php echo supported_languages() ?>
            </span>
        </a>
``
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm dropdown-menu-right text-right">
            <?php foreach(supported_languages() as $key => $value){ ?>
            <?php if( getUserlang()!=$key ) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo url('profil_language/change_language/'.$key.'?back='.urlencode(current_url())) ?>" class="dropdown-item"><?php echo $value->name.' <span class="text-muted">.$value->nativeName.')</span>' ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </li>
            
<!-- Fin menu langue -->

I also use a controller profil_language with this content:
public function change_language($code = '')
{
    return redirect()->to(!empty($_REQUEST['back']) ? urldecode($_REQUEST['back']) : '/' )->setCookie('current_lang', $code, time()+86400*30);
}


}

